# Tagged Type vs class extends AnyVal

Tags: scala, shapeless

To introduce more type safety, we can either use tagged type provided by `shapeless` or create a class which extends `AnyVal`. What are the differences and advantage/disadvantage to use one over the other?

Example:

```
trait CountryCodeTag
type CountryCode = String @@ CountryCodeTag

class CountryCode(code: String) extends AnyVal
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`type CountryCode = String @@ CountryCodeTag`**

+ `String @@ CountryCodeTag` is a subtype of `String`, i.e. all methods from `String` can be used directly: `countryCode.toUpperCase`.

− `String @@ CountryCodeTag` can be accidentally used where some `String` is expected, i.e. it's less type-safe.

− Creating new values is a little awkward: `"a".asInstanceOf[String @@ CountryCodeTag]` or `val tagger = new Tagger[CountryCodeTag]; tagger("a")`.

− Dependence on Shapeless (although this can be done manually).

**`class CountryCode(code: String) extends AnyVal`**

+ It's more type-safe.

− Methods from `String` are available with some extra efforts:

```
class CountryCode(val code: String) extends AnyVal
new CountryCode(countryCode.code.toUpperCase)
```

or

```
class CountryCode(val code: String) extends AnyVal 
object CountryCode {
  def unapply(...) = ...
}
countryCode match { case CountryCode(code) => new CountryCode(code.toUpperCase) }
```

or

```
case class CountryCode(code: String) extends AnyVal
countryCode.copy(code = countryCode.code.toUpperCase)
```

+ Creating new values is a little more natural: `new CountryCode("a")`.

+ No extra dependencies (it's plain Scala).

Comment: Can you give me an example for the disadvantage:

```String @@ CountryCodeTag can be accidentally used where some String is expected```?

Comment: @gyoho
`val countryCode: String @@ CountryCodeTag = ???`
`case class Person(name: String)`
`Person(countryCode)`

Comment: From memory footprint perspective, which one do you think works better?

Comment: In runtime both `CountryCode`s are just `String`s (with methods [extracted](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html#step-1-extracting-methods) to companion object) so I guess there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: @gyoho note that there are many cases where an anyval class needs to be instantiated, losing its runtime benefits.

Comment: https://kubuszok.com/2017/tagged-or-anyval/

Answer (score 0):

These two methods also have different performance characteristics.

Tagged types, as opposed to value classes, prevent boxing even when their instances are used as e.g. elements of a list.

https://failex.blogspot.nl/2017/04/the-high-cost-of-anyval-subclasses.html